# Why is pandas not working and importing anymore?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I used this code before and it was working fine. Now no matter what I do `pandas` is not working. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling. I used the previous file that was working, none of it is working. Can you help me find out whats happening?
This code:

```
import pandas as pd

...
df = pd.read.csv('all_stocks_5yr')
```

causes the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-dc236c5894fa> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.read.csv('all_stocks_5yr')

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in __getattr__(name)
    261             return _SparseArray
    262 
--> 263         raise AttributeError(f"module 'pandas' has no attribute '{name}'")
    264 
    265 

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: Convert `pd.read.csv()` to `pd.read_csv()`.

Answer (score 1):

The command you are looking for is

```
pd.read_csv('filename')
```

Not

```
pd.read.csv('filename')
```

Answer (score 1):

pandas has function `read_csv()` not `read.csv()`.

try:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

the command you need here is 
`pd.read_csv('filepath')`. You can learn more about it: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6hclsVV-zY&t=66s)